# Equivalence of semidefinite decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

If we have an $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrix $A$ and we have two decompositions such that
$A = B B^T = C C^T$ for some $n \times n$ matrices $B$ and $C$.

Is it true that $B$ and $C$ are related by a unitary matrix? Specifically, is $B U = C$ for some unitary matrix $U$?

Comment: I guess no. Try to find a counterexample by choosing $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$.